# Transfering Postgres RDS from one AWS account to another with only certain schemas

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-dms

I'm having a Postgres RDS database that have many schemas in it. I want to move only certain schemas into another AWS account's RDS. The schemas I'm looking at to transfer is only approx 12GB.

I'm looking for a minimal downtime method that make use of CDC such as DMS rather than the traditional export-and-restore. That's also what I'm doing with MongoDB. Add some slaves to the set, wait for it to sync, promote a new master once sync up-to-date, terminate the old ones.

So is it possible to sync only certain schemas, Postgres RDS to Postgres RDS, using AWS DMS. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just curious, if using Aurora, have you looked into [cross account synchronization using logical replication](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/amazon-aurora-postgresql-cross-account-synchronization-using-logical-replication/)?

Using DMS, you can include/exclude based on one or more schemas. Table mapping rules can be applied to a source or target endpoint of a Data Migration Task.

If you wanted to sync only tables in a single schema, simply create a rule-type of selection and define the schema in the object-locator section the selection criteria. You can use the "%" to include all tables in the schema.

```
"rules": 
    [
        {
            "rule-type": "selection",
            "rule-id": "1",
            "rule-name": "include-public-schema-only",
            "object-locator": {
                "schema-name": "public",
                "table-name": "%"
            },
            "rule-action": "include",
            "filters": []
        },
        ...
    ]
```

You can read more about the mapping rules and how to apply in the aws  [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TableMapping.SelectionTransformation.Selections.html).

If minimal downtime is your ultimate goal, the fastest way to get data to the target would be to upload a backup, restore at the target. Then set the DMS Task's (CDC) recovery checkpoint to correspond with the backup checkpoint of the source.